# NetBeans always shows warning: "The authenticity of host x can't be established" after upload, download or synchronize

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, rsa-key-fingerprint

I'm currently using NetBeans 6.9 with the PHP plugin and a PHP Application from Remote Server project. However, every time I upload or download with it, I'm prompted with a warning that reads:

> The authenticity of host x can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is y. Are you sure you want to continue connecting?

Can I store the RSA key fingerprint of the remote server or not have NetBeans confirm the key before taking action?

I'm connecting to my own server, so yes, I always trust it. Getting that popup is annoying and I would like to be able to simply have a way of either checking the key against a stored key and telling me if the key changes or just connecting to the server I tell it to, regardless of the RSA key fingerprint.

Comment: FWIW, it's the same in NetBeans 6.8.

Comment: @Sonny - No, since it's about a tool. From the FAQ on what questions to ask here: "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Comment: Thanks. I guess I've been asking my NetBeans questions on the wrong site then.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can create an empty file and set it as the Known Hosts File in the Manage Remote Connections window. The next time you tell NetBeans to connect anyway, it will save the fingerprint in that file and stop bothering you. I think it's safe to assume that if the key changes, you will be prompted again.

1. Open an Explorer window and navigate to Documents/NetBeansProjects
2. Create a text file called KnownHosts.txt
3. In Netbeans right-click on a project
4. Click Properties
5. Click Run Configuration
6. Click Manage
7. Next to the input field Known Host Files click Browse
8. Navigate to the directory where you created the KnownHosts text file
9. Select that file
10. Click OK
11. Click OK
12. In the project upload something. The prompt will appear this one time but not again.

Comment: That worked for me. I just made a text file, called it "Known Hosts File", put it in the directory where I throw all of my NetBeans projects, and then set the Known Hosts File in the Manage Remote Connections window to be that file. After I said "yes" to make a connection, it wrote the host information to that file and never prompted me again. Thanks.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get to Manage Remote Connections window?

Comment: @Zorayr: Right-click on a project, click `Properties` then `Run Configuration` and `Manage...` next to the Remote Connection drop-down list.

Comment: I realize this is 4 years old, but to anyone who ends up here: If you are on Windows, you must save the known hosts file in a place netbeans can write to it. You can't put this in C:\ or program files or any folders that you can't save a file into without being an administrator. It seems obvious but I spent an hour fighting with this and I hope it helps you!

Comment: On linux system, authorize netbeans to write in this file.